# Test the length of elements in a list

Tags: python, list

```
def lengthgood(x):
    for i in x:
        if len(i)<13
            return i
        else:
            pass


def makeproperlist(x):
    return x.split(',')



attendancelist=makeproperlist(input("attendee list:"))
final_list=list(filter(lengthgood,attendancelist))
for i in finallist:
    print (i)
```

I want to write a programme of which I create a list in which only elements shorter than 14 can be a part of.

This is my code, but it keeps returning all the elements I put in, even if some of them are longer than 14?

I tried to print the `len(i)` and it says that it is 1 for every element in the list?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put a `return` within a loop; it'll only return the first element that matches your condition.

You also shouldn't be looping within your filter function, because you're actually looping over *characters of strings*, which are all length 1.

Therefore, the first character is always returning a truthy value, giving you back the initial input after filtering

---

You only need to check the input length, and filter functions should ideally return appropriate boolean conditions rather than truthy values (in your case `return i` is returning a non-empty string)

```
def lengthgood(x):
    return len(x)<13
```

If you don't need to use `filter()`, you can write a list comprehension

```
final_list=[a if len(a) < 13 for a in attendancelist]
```

Answer (score 0):

may be like that

```
flst = []

def croper(lst):
    for i in lst:
        flst.append(i) if len(i) < 13 else 0 


lst = input("attendee list:").split(',')
croper(lst)

print(flst)
```

or shorter

```
def croper(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if len(i) < 13] 

lst = input("attendee list:").split(',')

print(croper(lst))
```

Comment: I think that'll always append to the list. `else 0` isn't doing anything useful

Comment: @cricket_007 try it. it works, `else 0` it's sintax necessity

Comment: I consider it cleaner to move the if statement to its own line, I guess. And reserve ternary conditions to variable assignments and return statements

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a list but you not define it anywhere in program simply done it with simply one function `makeproperlist(x)`.
Try this code bro this will help you.

```
attendancelist=[]
while (True):
   ch=input("Enter c for continue and e for exit : ")
   if (ch=='c'):
       def makeproperlist(x):
           if x<=13:
               attendancelist.append(x)
           else:
               print("Enter number which is <= to 13.")
       makeproperlist(int(input("attendee list:")))
    elif (ch=='e'):
        break;
print("Your attendece list : ",attendancelist)
```